# Why is stationarity of an autoregressive process contigent upon location of the roots of the backshift polynomial?

Tags: time-series, stationarity

Recall that an $AR(p)$-process (with mean $0$) is defined by the following recurrence relation
$$
X_t = \phi_1X_{t-1} + \cdots + \phi_pX_{t-p} + Z_t
$$
where $Z_t$ is i.i.d. white noise. If we use the backshift operator
$$
B(X_t) = X_{t-1}
$$
then we can rewrite this recurrence relation as a polynomial in the operator $B$
$$
\phi(B)X_t = Z_t
$$
I keep running into the technical claim that the process is stationary if the roots of $\phi(B)$ (when considered as a complex valued polynomial) lie outside of the complex unit circle $e^{i\theta}$. Why is this true?

Comment: Although I don't fully understand it, I think this is an answer to your question: [When is an “ARIMA process” stationary?
](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/187196/when-is-an-arima-process-stationary?rq=1)

Comment: The answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/346448/whats-the-inverse-of-the-finite-polynomial-phi-p-in-an-armap-q-model/346463#346463) may answer your question (see [Kasparis 2006](https://econ.biu.ac.il/files/economics/shared/riedp_3-16.pdf) for more detailed proof).